# Need to keep a CSS transform on page load for "active" nav link

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

I have a navbar that uses CSS transform to extend a bar across the top of the link on hover. I would also like to have an #active id, so the corresponding link has the ending style applied to it. Due to the nature of CSS transform syntax, I cannot accomplish this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doXMog

```
#active:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top:2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    background: red;
    content: '';
}
```

For clarification, I would like the text color changed and the bar to be present on page load, the same style that is applied on :hover. Of course, this style is only applied when it's hovered over and accompanied by the animation.

Thanks for looking, hope someone has an idea.

Comment: 2 options. 1 - on each of your pages add an active class to the corresponding menu item. 2 - if you use a "master" page, then you need to  add the active class with javascript when clicking the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to apply `transform: scaleX(1)!important` to the active class. It has to be important or it will not work.

```
.active:before {
  transform: scaleX(1)!important;
}
```

If you are dynamically changing the content of the page upon click of the menu items, you can use javascript like this to toggle the active class.

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav');                     // Select '.nav' from document and store it in var menu 
document.onclick = function(e) {                               // when the document is clicked
  if (menu.contains(e.target)) {                               // if the menu contains the clicked element
    var active = menu.querySelector('.active');                // select the current active item from menu
    active.className = active.className.replace('active', ''); // remove the active class from the currently active item
    e.target.className += 'active';                            // add the active class to the clicked element
  }
}
```

([Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGBKOv))

In the example above I've take the liberty of fixing the list markup in your html.

The only direct descendants of a ul element should be li elements.

You can achieve the same look and behavior if you nest the anchors inside the list items, then apply the styles you applied to the list items to the anchors instead.